# javap not showing the annotation information in the decompiled class

Tags: java, javap

I have a jar with a simple java class like below

```
package org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting;

public class PackageAnnotation {
    @VisibleForTesting
    public void dummyMethod() {

    }
}
```

After decompiling the class with javap the annotation information is not showing up.

```
dmanna-m01:dummy dmanna$ javap PackageAnnotation.class
Compiled from "PackageAnnotation.java"
public class org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation {
  public org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation();
  public void dummyMethod();
}
```

Can someone let me know why the annotation information is missing in the decompiled class even though the `@VisibleForTesting` is annotation of type `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`?

```
dmanna-m01:dummy dmanna$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Guava Version -23.5-jre

I have already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3933119/785523) but the accepted answer does  not seem to be valid here.  As per the Java doc

> RetentionPolicy.class -  Annotations are to be recorded in the class
>   file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.

So javap should be able to show the annotation information for `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` also.

**EDIT**

```
dmanna-m01:dummy dmanna$ javap -c PackageAnnotation.class
Compiled from "PackageAnnotation.java"
public class org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation {
  public org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void dummyMethod();
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

Output of `javap -v`

```
dmanna-m01:dummy dmanna$ javap -v PackageAnnotation.class
Classfile /Users/dmanna/workspaces/java/eclipse/pkgcmp/target/classes/org/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation.class
  Last modified Feb 14, 2018; size 489 bytes
  MD5 checksum 06949d127e5f631f77060be1b1f09b60
  Compiled from "PackageAnnotation.java"
public class org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation
  minor version: 0
  major version: 49
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             // org/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation
   #2 = Utf8               org/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation
   #3 = Class              #4             // java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               <init>
   #6 = Utf8               ()V
   #7 = Utf8               Code
   #8 = Methodref          #3.#9          // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #9 = NameAndType        #5:#6          // "<init>":()V
  #10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #11 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #12 = Utf8               this
  #13 = Utf8               Lorg/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation;
  #14 = Utf8               dummyMethod
  #15 = Utf8               RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
  #16 = Utf8               Lcom/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting;
  #17 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #18 = Utf8               PackageAnnotation.java
{
  public org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 5: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Lorg/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation;

  public void dummyMethod();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
      0: #16()
    Code:
      stack=0, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       1     0  this   Lorg/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation;
}
SourceFile: "PackageAnnotation.java"
```

**EDIT 2**

I am still not seeing the annotation in `javap` if I use some RUNTIME retention policy (e.g - [Subscribe](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/eventbus/Subscribe.html) )

```
package org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy;

import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

public class PackageAnnotation {
    @Subscribe
    public void dummyMethod() {

    }
}
```

Output of `javap`

```
dmanna-m01:dummy dmanna$ javap PackageAnnotation.class
Compiled from "PackageAnnotation.java"
public class org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation {
  public org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation();
  public void dummyMethod();
}
```

Output of `javap -c`

```
dmanna-m01:dummy dmanna$ javap -c PackageAnnotation.class
Compiled from "PackageAnnotation.java"
public class org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation {
  public org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void dummyMethod();
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

Output of `javap -v`

```
dmanna-m01:dummy dmanna$ javap -v PackageAnnotation.class
Classfile /Users/dmanna/workspaces/java/eclipse/pkgcmp/target/classes/org/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation.class
  Last modified Feb 14, 2018; size 476 bytes
  MD5 checksum fd8b8e678ed771fa19193b73feae1acb
  Compiled from "PackageAnnotation.java"
public class org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation
  minor version: 0
  major version: 49
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #3.#16         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #17            // org/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation
   #3 = Class              #18            // java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               <init>
   #5 = Utf8               ()V
   #6 = Utf8               Code
   #7 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
   #8 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
   #9 = Utf8               this
  #10 = Utf8               Lorg/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation;
  #11 = Utf8               dummyMethod
  #12 = Utf8               RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
  #13 = Utf8               Lcom/google/common/eventbus/Subscribe;
  #14 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #15 = Utf8               PackageAnnotation.java
  #16 = NameAndType        #4:#5          // "<init>":()V
  #17 = Utf8               org/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation
  #18 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public org.debraj.pkgcmp.dummy.PackageAnnotation();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 5: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Lorg/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation;

  public void dummyMethod();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=0, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       1     0  this   Lorg/debraj/pkgcmp/dummy/PackageAnnotation;
    RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
      0: #13()
}
SourceFile: "PackageAnnotation.java"
```

Comment: @VisibleForTesting is a guava class. I saw it in the source code.

Comment: Have you tried with `javap -v`?

Comment: No but I tried with javap -c

Comment: What does the `-c` and the `-v` produce in the output? You should be seeing a `RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations` entry with a reference to the annotation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Updated the question with `-c` and `-v`. But why this annotation is `RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations`. As [the code](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.html#line.65) shows the type is having type `RententionPolicy.CLASS`.

Comment: That code is for a different annotation. `@VisibleForTesting`  has no explicit retention policy so it defaults to `CLASS`. It's runtime invisible because reflection operations should not return it at runtime.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  - As per my understanding `CLASS` type annotations are retained in the .class file. So `javap` should have been able to show it in decompiled class. Please check my edit 2 I am still not seeing the annotation in the output of `javap` even if I am using RUNTIME annotations.

Comment: _So javap should have been able to show it in decompiled class_ And it did, as you saw in the `RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations`. For `RUNTIME`, you see it in the `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` and it's available through reflection operations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can you please post your explanation in comment as an answer so that I can accept it?